# Intuition for behavior of Chebyshev bound

Tags: probability

Suppose that you flip a coin $n$ times and denote the number of heads that appear by $H_n$. You want to estimate the probability $p$ of a head Define an estimator $\hat p = H_n/n$ choose an $n$ large enough so that

$$
P(|H_n/n - p| \geq \epsilon) \leq \delta.
$$

By the Chebyshev bound, we have that

$$
P(|H_n/n - p| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{Var(H_n/n)}{\epsilon^2}
$$

or

$$
P(|H_n/n - p| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{Var(H_n)}{n^2\epsilon^2}.
$$

To compute $Var(H_n)$, we note that $H_n$ is a binomial random variable, and so $Var(H_n) = np(1-p)$. Plugging this in gives

$$
P(|H_n/n - p| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac{p(1-p)}{n\epsilon^2}.
$$

---

I'm interested in the following trends:

- If we cut $\epsilon$ in half, then $n$ would increase by a factor of $4$, right?
- If we cut $\delta$ in half, then $n$ would increase by a factor of $2$, right?

To come up with these hypotheses, I'm comparing my final expression for the bound to what it would be after making the change, and considering how $n$ must change.

Could someone confirm my thinking?

Comment: Looks right, but what is $\delta$?

Comment: $\delta$ is not specified in your post. Do you seek $n$ such that $P(|H/n - p| \geq \epsilon) \leq \delta$?